# How it's better to integrate rails#session into backbone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, backbone.js

First of all i've read [Integrating Devise with Backbone.js](http://joshhuckabee.com/integrating-devise-backbonejs). But the main thing - I don't use Devise.
Now i've created backbone views for signing up & authenticating (backbone simply connects to rails for backend support). what i want to know is - are there any possibilities of storing information about is user logged in or not & where do you advice to store it, or i'll have to connect to the backend when i need info?

**Update 1**
I tried to store user after login in the global variable, which is declared in router (backbone)

```
class Notes.Routers.Articles extends Backbone.Router
  currentUser: null
```

in one view

```
@currentUser = response // it's a response object from ajax call
 Backbone.history.navigate("articles",true)
```

and in the target view

```
 console.log  @currentUser
```

It doesn't work , any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out the "gon" gem - it provides access to rails session information, and anything else you want from rails, in your JavaScript environment. I used this in a project with a client once and it worked really well.

If you don't want to do anything like that, then the "easy" way is to just dump rendered session info out to your JavaScript code directly.

For example, you can do something like this in a view template:

```
window.currentUser = {
  name: ""
};
```

and this will give you access to `currentUser.name` anywhere in your JavaScript code.

Comment: don't store it in your router. this forces you to always have access through your router instance, which is the problem your running in to. you're trying to access a variable that doesn't exist in the scope your access it from. store it on the global 'window' or your application's root namespace object, but never an instance of a specific type like a router